# Pandas wide_to_long ignoring a column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use the pandas wide_to_long function on my dataframe. But as shown in the screen shots below, the wide_to_long function is not processing the '16a' column while '15' and '16' are processed properly.

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Thank you in advance,

Sida

[result_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6nuo.png)

[wide_to_long](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxEsE.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.